# Match the pattern TEXT[0,0]

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a lot of source codes with SQL queries like below:

```
c_query := "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE FIELD_NAME_ONE[2] = 'AB' AND FIELD_NAME_TWO[1,8] = 'ABCDEFGH'"
```

I would like to match these: `FIELD_NAME_ONE[2]` and `FIELD_NAME_TWO[1,8]` and these patterns must be found between double quotes (`"`).

Edit

c_query := "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE FIELD_NAME_ONE[2] = 'AB' AND FIELD_NAME_TWO[1,8] = 'ABCDEFGH' AND TESTE[9] = 'XXXXXXXXX' AND FOO = '" + is_an_array[2] + "'"

It shouldn´t match is_an_array[2] because is not inside the double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to be able to match more than just those two specific fields, otherwise you wouldn't have gone to the trouble of applying regular expressions:

```
var tokens = Regex.Matches(sql, "\"([^\"]+)\"");

foreach (Match token in tokens) {
    string str = token.Groups[1].Value;

    var fields = Regex.Matches(str, @"(\w+\[\d+(,\d+)*\])");

    foreach (Match field in fields)
        Console.WriteLine(field.Value);
}
```

This will find any sequence of letters, numbers and underscores followed by square brackets, with 1 or more comma-separated numbers.

If you only want to match a sequence of letters and underscores before the square brackets, ammend the pattern to:

```
@"([a-zA-Z_]+\[\d+(,\d+)*\])"
```

Comment: But I can have more than one query in the same string, how can I do it to work.

Comment: That is more complicated. Do the queries themselves contain any (possibly escaped) double-quotes? eg: `select * from table where col = '"hey there", he said.'`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a regex pattern for what you seek (edited based on comment):

```
".*?[A-Z_]+\[\d(,\d)?\].*?"
```

I made the match non-greedy (`.*?`) in case there are multiple matches on the one line (unlikely, but for completeness...)

#### Edited

It's not clear if you want to match *just* the target field names or the whole SQL. If you want to match just the field names alone, use non-capturing groups for the rest:

```
(?:".*?)[A-Z_]+\[\d(,\d)?\](?:.*?")
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/256196/bohemian But I can have many other texts before the square brackets and random numbers inside brackets..... A1_NOME[5], F2_NOME[3,5], etc.....N[x,y]

Comment: @Will maybe you should have said that in your question. See edited answer. How big can the indexes be - eg can you get `FIELD[999,9999]`? Are all field names in all-capitals?